# Прошу совета по WP_Query

Tags: wordpress, фильтр, wp-query

На сайте использую Advanced Custom Fields + его плагин Repeater Field, в итоге есть субполе, по которому нужно сделать сортировку (вывести все записи с ним заполненным). Делаю так :

```
if( $_GET['box'] != '' ){
    global $wp_query;
    $args = array(
            'cat' => 1,

            'meta_query'     => array(
                'relation'      => 'AND',
                array(
                    'key'     => 'sizes_and_prices_%_size_box',
                    'value'   => $_GET['box'],
                    'compare' => 'LIKE',
                )
            )
         );

    query_posts(array_merge($args, $wp_query->query));

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Ну и далее вывод найденных страниц. В итоге пишет 0 записей.
Пробовал и отключать обработку входных данных через suppress_filters, и ставить фильтры на WP Query, все равно не пашет (трижды перечитал инструкцию [вот отсюда](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/create-a-filter-by-repeater-sub-field/) и [отсюда](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/query-posts-custom-fields/), там предлагают юзать конструкцию с хуком, которая у меня почему то не работает)

```
 function my_posts_where( $where ) {
    $where = str_replace("meta_key = 'locations_%", "meta_key LIKE 'locations_%", $where);
    return $where;
}

add_filter('posts_where', 'my_posts_where');
```

В итоге распечатал объект запроса и вижу в нем вот такую интересную штуку:

```
[request] => SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID 
FROM wp_posts  
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) WHERE 1=1  AND ( 
  wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (1)
) 
AND ( 
  ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'sizes_and_prices_**{583c9e0a918e788d221b2095277a5e69fc88f41e4e947f5659b42df6daafbc45}**_size_box' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value LIKE '{583c9e0a918e788d221b2095277a5e69fc88f41e4e947f5659b42df6daafbc45}2.5м2-3.5м2{583c9e0a918e788d221b2095277a5e69fc88f41e4e947f5659b42df6daafbc45}' )
) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 6
```

Т.е. насколько я понял, WP сам заменяет % на кракозябры во имя безопасности. И да, если поставить нужный индекс вместо %, моя конструкция работает. Просто делать мегакостыль из повторения 20 по сути одинаковых условий крайне не хочется.

Внимание, вопрос: что делать? =)

Comment: я так понял ты подмешивает запрос WP_Query  в основной query_posts - query_posts(array_merge($args, $wp_query->query)); Лучше тоже поменять на WP_Query главный запрос который сейчас через  query_posts

Comment: Делал изначально вот по этой инструкции - http://dontforget.pro/wordpress/filtr-postov-po-proizvolnyim-polyam-v-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так

```
        function my_posts_where( $where ) {
            global $wpdb;
            $where = str_replace("meta_key = 'sizes_and_prices_%", "meta_key LIKE 'sizes_and_prices_%", $wpdb->remove_placeholder_escape($where));
            return $where;
        }
        add_filter('posts_where', 'my_posts_where');
```

Comment: у тебя в $_GET['box'] передается массив из значений из нескольких sub_fields?

Comment: В $_GET['box'] передается строка с одним значением. Выборка делается не по значению, а по имени поля.

Comment: По поводу предложенного варианта:
если распечатать входные данные ($where), то там кусок вообще не относящийся к нужной части запроса приходит, а именно:

AND ( 
  wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (1)
) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private')

Comment: О, заработало, надо было еще удалить строчку 'suppress_filters' => TRUE

Спасибо большое!